# channel id not recognised in discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to connect to the second channel of the server but it seems like it doesnt exist throwin an error when executing :

```
 /home/ser356/Escritorio/node discord/app.js:11
        channel.send("ola");
                ^
    
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')


/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
    

const {Client,Intents} = require("discord.js");
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});
    
    client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
    
    
       
        const channel =  client.channels.cache.get('950537341280325632')
        channel.send("hola");

I don't know what i'm doing wrongg because i've copied exactly the id from discord.
```

Edit: i add the .env file too

```
BOT_TOKEN="OTUwNTQyNDQ5MzYzODA4MzA2.YiabpA.bulmNmwGgz9s8kOPyvjngR_rSbo"
```

Update

Solved adding an event before logging in:

```
const {Client,Intents} = require("discord.js");
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_>
var arguments=process.argv[2];
console.log(arguments)
//client.login("OTUwNTQyNDQ5MzYzODA4MzA2.YiabpA.bulmNmwGgz9s8kOPyvjngR_rSbo");
client.on('ready', () => {
var canal =  client.channels.cache.get("950644612517724171")
if(arguments==='start'){
canal.send("klk")
}
else if(arguments==='stop'){
canal.send("klwa")
}
else{
canal.send("nada")
}
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using client,

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
      if(message.author.bot) return;
      const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "950537341280325632")
      return channel.send("Testing for stackoverflow").catch((err) => console.log(err))
    })
```

Take note that every chat you'll do your bot will send again.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/app.js:7:9) It's still throwing the same error i dont know why. Ps: you forgot to close With })

Comment: after `channel.send("hola")` put a `.catch((err) => console.log(err))`

Comment: I think you dont get my question, it's not reading the id, i've tryied the assignment by an asynchronous función, catching the promise, logging only the cache from the Channel id etc etc etc but it's still dropping me undefinded or error like if the Channel was not created ever

Comment: try to do `.find` instead of `.get`

Comment: undefined const channel =  client.channels.cache.find('950537341280325632');
console.log(channel)

Comment: can you post all of your codes here? Cause it's very weird with that error

Comment: the Code is exactly as i provided cause i get this error at start and the .env file is like: BOT_TOKEN="OTUwNTQyNDQ5MzYzODA4MzA2.YiabpA.bulmNmwGgz9s8kOPyvjngR_rSbo"

Comment: hide your token

Comment: What do you mean? I've done It, With the .env file, and passing the token as a string arg too, the token is correct and the client logs in perfectly

Comment: I mean your token should be your secret id, you're the who should only know about your token + check my edit post

Comment: Really don't care bout my token , test purposes only

Comment: So did it work then?

Comment: Yes, i added an event to get id before login in

Comment: If you get any idea of my post, please leave a mark and vote solution. thank you

Comment: Not really at all, as i told u on the comments i have done everything you said